# Change last name on ITIN

Tags: united-states, itin

How can I change my spouse's last name after marriage on ITIN? My spouse has an updated passport with a new last name. Is IRS going to send my spouse a new ITIN card?

I was looking at [this](https://www.irs.gov/newsroom/a-name-change-affects-a-tax-return) but couldn't find anything related to changing the name on ITIN. It all talks about SSN which is not applicable to my spouse at this point in time.

Answer (score 2):

From: [IRS Pub. 1915 - Understanding Your IRS Individual Taxpayer Identification Number (ITIN)](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/p1915.pdf), page 6:

> **What do I do if my name has changed since I
> received my ITIN?**
>
> If the change affects your legal name, you will need to request a name
> change by sending a letter directly to the address listed under "Where
> do I file my Form W-7/W-7(SP)?", later. Include an explanation of the
> circumstances leading to the change (marriage, divorce, etc.) and
> submit documentation to support your request. Examples include:
>
> - A copy of a marriage license.
> - A copy of a divorce certificate.
> - An official court related document validating the name change.

See the above linked IRS PDF for details.

You may also wish to review:
[ITIN Application - IRS requesting original passport](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/21501/14319) and [What to do about not having an ITIN for spouse if IRS isn't being responsive?](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/27204/14319)